# Многопоточность Java (механизм создания отдельного/нового потока)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Заранее скажу, что ниже будет немного воды, так как я ниже попытаюсь максимально точно и понятно описать суть своего вопроса.

Возможно покажется вопрос простым, но речь не о том, как можно создать поток общепринятыми способами, и что для этого надо использовать. Мне надо понять, каким образом Java на основе Thread-а, Runnable-а и методов run() и start() создает отдельный поток.

В смысле, скажем, ну просто теоретический возьмем, что я захочу в один прекрасный день написать такой класс, по подобии Thread но не наследоваться от самого Thread а вообще отдельный класс создать, каким то образом пытаться сделать его таким же как и Thread, чтоб он мог сам без помощи Thread и Runnable, создавать или просто помочь создавать новые потоки, как это делает Thread вместе с Runnablе.

Что я должен буду для этого сделать? 
Ну или просто суть вопроса: как удается Thread вместе Runnable создавать отдельный поток?

Мне интересует сам механизм этого процесса создания и включения в работу программы нового потока.

дополнительно: Пожалуйста, обязательно укажите в ответе чем механизм создания нового потока отличается от создания и вызова потока метода main().

Comment: Очень широкий вопрос. Если глянете в класс `Thread`, то увидите, что создание потока происходит при вызове native метода `start0()`, который в свою очередь вызывается при вызове `start()`. В конечном итоге это все должно свестись к системному вызову в ядре ос (для linux это `clone()`), который создаст поток, зарегает его в планировщике, выделит память и сделает еще кучу всего. Т.к. разных ос много, то и работа этой функции будет отличаться в зависимости от ос. Немного упрощает ситуацию наличие стандартов и библиотек (типа POSIX), который поддерживает большое кол-во UNIX систем.

Comment: Но вопрос реально большой, с удовольствием почитаю полноценный ответ :)

Comment: хорошо, значит в первую очередь, надо обратить внимание на native методы и тонкостям их работы.

Comment: уже наводит на некоторые интересные мысли, но жаль, что пока смутные))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Пожалуйста, обязательно укажите в ответе чем механизм создания нового
>   потока отличается от создания и вызова потока метода main().

Ничем

Цепочка выглядит так:
 - Вы пишите код, который просит JVM создать поток
 - JVM просит ОС создать поток
 - ОС создаёт поток и регулирует его исполнение.

У ОС есть ресурсы CPU и она выделение их для конкретных потоков, регулирует какой поток и сколько будет занимать ресурсы.
Есть "Задача об обедающих философах". Когда за ограниченные ресурсы борются несколько потребителей. Это уровень ОС, это её задача. Поэтому, решать это нужно не на Java.

Comment: Спасибо за четкий ответ.

Answer (score 7):

Если посмотреть исходники метода [`Thread#start`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l713), то видно, что там вызывается метод:

```java
private native void start0();
```

то есть запуск потока реализован как-то нативно. Если хочется написать свой класс `class MyOwnBestThread`, то придется использовать jni, чтобы создавать нативные потоки.